# linked list in c, unexpected results

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new at programming and am trying to learn linked lists. I've decided to experiment with linked lists by writing a simple program that will read from a file, one character at a time, and insert each character into a linked list. Then I print the linked list out. Simple, right? Well, maybe not if it's your first time. I'm following the online tutorials oh, so carefully, but my output isn't what it's supposed to be. (The program compiles and runs with no errors or warnings. I'm using Code Blocks.) Instead of getting any characters, I get two numbers, and that's all.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Tokens_read_in{
    char character;
    int number;
    char whichOne[5];
    struct Tokens_read_in* next;
}Tokens;

int main()
{

    //declare variables
    char c;

    //create a struct for the array that will hold the tokens
    Tokens* token_array;
    token_array = malloc(sizeof(Tokens));
    token_array->next = NULL;

    //open the input file
    FILE *ifp;  //input file pointer
    char *filename = "input.txt";
    ifp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if(!ifp){
        printf("Error in opening '%s' for reading!", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    while(!feof(ifp)){

        //prepare to read in file one character at a time
        c = getc(ifp);

        //create a struct for the current token that is read in
        Tokens* current_token = token_array;

        //let the current_token point to the beginning of token_array
        current_token = token_array;

        //let the current_token point to the LAST of token_array
        while(current_token->next != NULL){
            current_token = current_token->next;
        }

        //create a node at the end of token_array
        current_token->next = malloc(sizeof(Tokens));

        //move the current_token to the last (new) of token_array
        current_token = current_token->next;
        if(current_token == NULL){
            printf("Out of memory");
            exit(0);
        }

        //plug character into current_token
        current_token->next = NULL;
        //letter
        if(isalpha(c)){
            printf("%c", c);
            current_token->character = c;
            strcpy(current_token->whichOne, "char");
        }
        //number
        else if(isdigit(c))
        {
            printf("%d", (int)c);
            current_token->number = (int)c;
            strcpy(current_token->whichOne, "num");
        }
        //space
        //this does not need to go into the token array
        else if (c == ' '){
            printf(" ");
        }
        //newline
        //this does not need to go into the token array
        else if (c == '\n'){
            printf("\n");
        }
        //anything else
        else if ((!isdigit(c) && !isalpha(c))){
            printf("%c", c);
            current_token->character = c;
            strcpy(current_token->whichOne, "char");
        }

        //now that the current_token is plugged into token_array, free current_token
        free(current_token);

    }//end while(!feof(ifp))

    //print the token_array
    Tokens* conductor;
    conductor = token_array;
    while(conductor != NULL){
        if(strcmp(conductor->whichOne, "num")){
            printf("%d ", conductor->number);
        }
        else if(strcmp(conductor->whichOne, "char")){
            printf("%c ", conductor->character);
        }
        conductor = conductor->next;
    }
    //done printing, so free conductor
    free(conductor);

    //done with program, so free token_array
    free(token_array);

    //close input file
    fclose(ifp);

    return 0;
}//end main
```

And here is the input file I'm using (named input.txt):

```
<I don't know why every beginner program says hello world,
but hello world anyway.>
```

I really appreciate anyone who looks at this and points me into the right direction.

Comment: Every beginner program says 'hello world' because the  classic text *The C Programming Language* starts with a program that prints "Hello, world!".

Comment: There are several major flaws with your program that need to be fixed before you can proceed. The first flaw is that you're resetting and traversing your list through each iteration of gathering a new character. This is completely unnecessary if you just hold on to the root (first) node and the terminal (last) node. Next, you declare a stack variable to point to the root node and assign it twice in a row. Lastly, you free the node that you've just initialized, thereby creating a linked list of invalid pointers. You need a better understanding of C and pointers to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 5):

You should not free current_token at the end of your read loop. This will cause problems, because you are freeing memory of a node that is inside your linked list.

Also, as a side note, isdigit succeeds when given a character that represents a digits, so character '1' for instance. You should still be using %c to print this out, because %d will give you the ascii number for character '1'.

Comment: The way I understood it, once the current_token was 'plugged into' the token_array, the token_array kind of takes over so that everything you plug into it will still exist, even when current_token is freed. Did I understand this completely wrong - am I way off? If so, where should I free current_array - should I free it along with free(token_array)? Or if the two are still intertwined somehow, does that mean I only have to free token_array and that will automatically get rid of current_array?

Answer (score 4):

You need `if (strcmp(a,b)==0)` to test for equality.

Comment: This is one of the biggest problems you are having. You're using your number printing for characters, and character printing for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

- You absolutely do not want to `free(current_token)`.
- If you want to convert a char to an int, a simple way (in ASCII) to do that is:

```
    char c = '3';
    int i = c - '0';
    printf("As a char: %c\n", c); // Prints 3.
    printf("As an int: %d\n", i); // Prints 3.
```

- When you malloc data, it is possible and likely that there will be random data in that region. You should clear your entire struct once you malloc it with a memset.
- As mentioned in other answers, strcmp returns 0 on a match. That means that you are doing the inverse of the comparison that you want.
- The data in your struct is quite odd when the character is a space or newline. This is because the data starts in an undetermined state.

If you fix the above errors (excluding the memset), The output from your program is much more like what you want.

Answer (score 1):

strcmp returns zero when two string are equal

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strcmp.html

and presumably you want to avoid the eof character.

in line 99 you want

```
conductor = (token_array->next);
```

instead of

```
conductor = token_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//now that the current_token is plugged into token_array, free current_token
        free(current_token);

    }//end while(!feof(ifp))
```

Try commenting the call to `free(current_token);`

The job of malloc and free are to keep track of what memory has been allocated. When you call free, the next malloc call may be sending you back the same memory address you just used.

Additionally

```
//create a struct for the current token that is read in
Tokens* current_token = token_array;

//let the current_token point to the beginning of token_array
current_token = token_array;
```

The second assignment is redundant. Not a bug (yet), but just a note for a new programmer.

Also, let us know what numbers you are getting. Getting numbers instead of characters can sometimes indicate you are outputting ASCII codes instead of the characters themselves.